# internet DSL, internal PCI Modem

Tags: command-line, networking, ip, pci, dsl

I want to connect to the internet by phone cable through my pc's internal PCI modem.
I also have a ethernet pci card, but the goal is to not use it .
Is it possible ?

```
root@xubuntu:~# lspci -d 8086:1080
00:0a.0 Modem: Intel Corporation FA82537EP 56K V.92 Data/Fax Modem PCI (rev 03)
root@xubuntu:~#

root@xubuntu:~# ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:bf:33:58:f4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
root@xubuntu:~#
```

Comment: DSL connectivity requires a DSL modem. V.92 faxmodems are incompatible with DSL.

Comment: then why is it written "phone line" on the card ?

Comment: Because it's a *dialup* (pre-broadband) modem. Popular 1985-2000. It's literally a phone and makes phone calls - it dials a number and connects to another modem at the other end.

Comment: so it can be used for a dial-up internet connection by the dsl cable,right ?

Comment: No. There is no such thing as "a dial-up internet connection by the dsl cable".

Comment: oops, i reformulate: this card that make phone calls,can be used for internet,because its possible to access servers by phone calls,right?

Comment: If you have a dial-up account with an Internet Service Provider, then yes. You may find the data transfer rate a bit slow...which is why most people moved to DSL and other alternatives. Also, you cannot send or receive phone calls while online. If your telephone billing is metered by time, modem calls count on the meter.